# Does this saying be equivalent to group isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Assume H,K are two given groups, if for all groups G, homomorphisms from G to H is one-to-one corresponding to homomorphisms from G to K, is H isomorphic to K ?
I believe it is true, but I can't find a way to prove it. And, evidently, if H and K are isomorphic, the property is naturally satisfied.
And, 'groups' in this saying can be replaced by 'objects' , 'homomorphisms' can be replaced by 'morphisms'

Comment: Do you want the identifications of $\text{Hom}(G,H)$ to $\text{Hom}(G,K)$ to be natural in $G$? Then the statement follows from the covariant Yoneda lemma.

Comment: I don't know whether it is enough to be proved, but, I think it is pretty fundemental, does it really need Yoneda lemma?

Comment: Well, the Yoneda lemma itself is "pretty fundamental"... In general, this may not be true if you don't require the bijections to be natural (see for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3242720/isomorphism-of-hom-sets-implies-objects-are-isomorphic?noredirect=1&lq=1)), although I'm not sure how to find a counterexample in the category of groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!