# A difficulty in proving $Y^{T_1\oplus T_2}\cong Y^{T_1}\otimes Y^{T_2}$ in an arbitrary category

Tags: category-theory, exponentiation

I've been struggling to write a complete proof following the guide provided in [1]. As showed in the book, I constructed the potential isomorphisms $\alpha:Y^{T_1 +T_2}\rightarrow Y^{T_1}\times Y^{T_2}$ and $\beta:Y^{T_1}\times Y^{T_2}\rightarrow Y^{T_1+ T_2}$. For details and notation, please refer to the following link: [Construction of potential isomorphisms](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mH4qefRHBCP6iMqMrYRrjgr4Gx7mA-bB/view?usp=sharing) (For some reason, equations are not showing on the direct link, please try opening in google docs which seem to work fine).

My strategy was to show that
$$e_Y\circ (1_{T_1+ T_2}\times (\beta \circ \alpha))=e_Y$$
(where $e_Y$ is the evaluation map $(T_1 + T_2)\times Y^{T_1+ T_2}\rightarrow Y$

which I attempted as following:

By using distributive property of $\times$ over $\circ$,
$$e_Y\circ (1_{T_1+ T_2}\times \beta)\circ (1_{T_1+ T_2}\times \alpha)=e_Y$$

Now substituting $e_Y\circ (1_{T_1+ T_2}\times \beta)=\beta_p$ from step 9 of $\beta$'s construction.

$$\beta_p \circ (1_{T_1+T_2}\times \alpha)=e_Y$$

Substituting the definition of $\beta_p$

$$e''_Y \circ (1_{Y^{T_1} \times Y^{T_2}}\times (\delta_1 + \delta_2))\circ \gamma  \circ ((1_{T_1+ T_2}\times \alpha)=e_Y$$

where $\delta_1 = \lceil e_{Y_1} \circ (1_{T_1} \times p_1) \circ \gamma'_1 \rceil$ and $\delta_2 = \lceil e_{Y_2} \circ (1_{T_2} \times p_2) \circ \gamma'_2 \rceil$.

This is where I got stuck. I tried using the distributive property (which is not yet introduced at the point in the book. It is right after this exercise) to distribute $1_{Y^{T_1} \times Y^{T_2}}$ over $(\delta_1 +\delta_2))$ because then I could use step 5 from $\beta$'s construction.

Thanks in Advance. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

References:

[1] F. William Lawvere and Stephen H. Schanuel's Conceptual Mathematics.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the notation of this book. What are $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ here? Coproduct and product? Is $\otimes$ an arbitrary symmetric monoidal product? Is exponentiation an internal hom wrt $\otimes$ whatever that turns out to be?

Comment: @jgon Sorry, I used unusual notation. $\otimes$ and $\oplus$ are product and co-product operations in an arbitrary category. (I suppose, $X$ and $+$ are more common.) Exponentiation is the exponential object as per definition here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+object

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using $\otimes$ to denote the categorical product; in a categorical context $\otimes$ is used almost exclusively to denote a monoidal product (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category) which typically differs from either the product or the coproduct, e.g. the tensor product of vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you @QiaochuYuan for making me aware of it. I'll edit the question to correct the notation.

Answer (score 2):

Though it's possible to manipulate the morphisms directly, it's much easier to work with the universal properties at the level of natural isomorphisms of hom-sets, as in the following. I've left out the justification for each step: see if you can see why each step is justified, and why this implies the property you are trying to establish. (I'm going to use the standard notation for coproduct and product, for anyone coming across this question in the future.)

\begin{align}\mathscr C(X, Y^{T_1 + T_2}) & \cong \mathscr C(X \times (T_1 + T_2), Y) \\ & \cong \mathscr C(X \times T_1 + X \times T_2, Y) \\ & \cong \mathscr C(X \times T_1, Y) \times \mathscr C(X \times T_2, Y) \\ & \cong \mathscr C(X, Y^{T_1}) \times \mathscr C(X, Y^{T_2}) \\ & \cong \mathscr C(X, Y^{T_1} \times T^{T_2})\end{align}

(Note: I'm not quite sure where this exercise appears in the book, so I'm not sure whether any of the above will be new. Let me know if anything is unclear, and I will update my answer.)

Comment: I'm not sure that the typing here works out; $X$ seems to be an object of $\textbf{Set}$, whereas $T_{1}+T_{2}$ need not be, whence $X\times\left(T_{1}+T_{2}\right)$ does not seem to me immediately well-defined.

Comment: @RafayAshary: $X$ is an (arbitrary) object of $\mathscr C$, not a set.

Comment: But then there are the following obstructions: 1. It's not obvious how $Y^{T_{1}+T_{2}}$ should be an object of $\mathscr C$, and 2. Binary products do not generally distribute over binary coproducts.

Comment: @RafayAshary: $Y^{T_1 + T_2}$ is an object of $\mathscr C$ by definition. Assuming $\mathscr C$ is cartesian-closed and has coproducts (as indicated by the notation), then $X \times (T_1 + T_2) \cong X \times T_1 + X \times T_2$, because $X \times (-)$ is a left adjoint and thus preserves colimits.

Comment: Ah, then you're right; I didn't notice OP's requirement that $\mathscr{C}$ be Cartesian closed in their clarification.

Comment: @varkor Thanks for taking the time to help me. (Un)fortunately, this is new. I have not seen this before. So, I am going to take my time to understand this. If you have any suggestions about what should I learn before I try to understand this, please do let me know.

Comment: @varkor Is the notation $\mathscr{C}(X, Y)$ (for example) suppose to represent Hom-set of maps from X to Y?

Comment: @jaspreet: yes, I'm using that notation for hom-sets. The concepts this involves are: adjunctions (specifically the hom-set characterisation for exponential objects), the universal properties of products and coproducts, and that left adjoints preserve colimits. (And implicitly, the [Yoneda lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704891/if-operatornamehomx-and-operatornamehomy-are-isomorphic-why-a).) If you like, I can spell it out explicitly, but I think understanding these three concepts should be enough to understand the whole proof.