# If we know any homomorphism between fixed group $G$ and arbitrary group $F$, could we determine $G$?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, group-homomorphism

What I want to prove is :  there does not exist two non-isomorphism group $G_1,G_2$ satisfy $Hom(G_1,F)=Hom(G_2,F)$ for any group $F$, here $Hom$ are hom in the  category of all group. Or If you like, the category of all small group $Grp$, i.e. the group whose underlying structure is set. And $Hom(A,B)=Hom(C,B)$ is up to natrual isomorphism (there exist $f_B \in Hom(A,C)$ s.t. for any $p_B \in Hom(A,B)$ there exist $q_B \in Hom(C,B) s.t. q_Bf=p_B$ and conversely there exist $f'_B \in Hom(C,A)$ s.t. $p'_Bf'_B=q'_B$. And  with another group $D$, and group homomorphism $k: B\to D$ and $f_D,f'_D$,satisfy $kp_Bf_B=f_Dkp_D$)

When $F={e}$ we know cardinal of $G$. I think Yoneda lemma may help, but as far as I know, the category of all group is not a locally small category.
If this is wrong, please give a counter-example

Update: Yoneda lemma indeed solve the $Grp$ case, but I intended to prove for group that is not small.

Comment: Is the question equivalent to: "let $X$ be some set, $\circ_1$ and $\circ_2$ be two operations on it s.t. $(X, \circ_1)$ and $(X, \circ_2)$ are groups, and for any group $F$ and function $h: X \to F$, $h$ is $\circ_1$-homomorphism iff $h$ is $\circ_2$ homomorphism, then $\circ_1 = \circ_2$"?

Comment: @mihaild Almost, but when X is not a set there may exist some problems. And I am not really familiar with that condition.

Comment: @mihaild I could not find that question or related one on bing, may you give me a reference? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is just my attempt to give alternative formulation that I would understand better (I have troubles to see how can $Hom$, which is set of function, be the same if we consider functions on different domains), not some well-known question. I am not sure how you can speak about group without having set that supports it - what is the problem with $X$ being a set?

Comment: @mihaild there are some groups whose underlying structure is not a set, though wiki's definition need a set. Nevermind, I just know there is a strange class of group and what I hope was a category-theory-like answer, but you can use wiki's definition freely to prove or disprove. What I really mean is just the last sentence.

Comment: 1) The category of groups *is* locally small. 2) What does it mean to have *equal* hom-sets for possibly distinct objects? 3) If you relax this condition to saying that there is a natural isomorphism of Hom-sets (natural in $F$) then Yoneda tells you that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are canonically isomorphic.

Comment: I don't know much about category theory, but from just set-theoretic point of view (assuming you wanted $fq = p$, not $fp = q$), if $G_1$ is isomorphic to normal subgroup of $G_2$, $G_2$ is isomorphic to normal subgroup of $G_1$, but $G_1$ isn't isomorphic to $G_2$, then it's counterexample - is it so?

Comment: Who told you that $\mathbf{Grp}$ is not locally small? Also, what does it mean for two random hom-sets to be equal? The condition is ill-typed.

Comment: @JonasLinssen  sorry for wrong typo, I mean the category of all group, not just small group. $Grp$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\operatorname{Hom}(X,-)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(Y,-)$ are isomorphic, why are $X$ and $Y$ isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704891/if-operatornamehomx-and-operatornamehomy-are-isomorphic-why-a)